# Is it a good practice to use LocalbroadcastManager and ResultReceiver to update progress bar?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

After a long searching for the solution to retain the progress bar view while switching the fragment. You can find the whole description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668285/how-to-retain-progress-bar-state-while-switching-the-fragments)

I just wanted to know if i will use LocalBroadcastManager and ResultReceiver to receive the progress update of every Byte is it a bad practice ?
(I am using IntentService to download data from the server)

Comment: use `ResultReceiver` and deliver a result to this receiver  when for example one percent or more of the file was downloaded

Comment: I have to show 6 to 7 numbers of progress bar at a time in worst condition.
Doesn't it degrade the performance of our application ?

Comment: 6 to 7 numbers? what do you mean?

Comment: I am managing a grid view and on every view one progress bar is there that will be activated once the use click on that view. So in worst condition i have to show 6 to 7 progress bar at a time.

Comment: ok, it souldnt be a problem then